# Converting 2K18 year into 2018

Tags: sql, date

In My scenario I have a table with year from 1000 to Present in the format of 2k18.

I want change that year into 2018.

Comment: so, which DBMS are you using?

Comment: You should provide some test data. Otherwise nobody can help you. How is the year stored? Alone in a year column or as part of date?

Comment: How is year e.g 1998 written??

Comment: replace k with 0

Comment: Hint:  `replace(year, 'k', '0')`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somthing like

```
update tableName
set yearColumn = Replace(yearColumn, 'k', '0')
where yearColumn like '_k__'
```

But that depends on your data and if only years are stored in the table. And also which DBMS you are using